# Convert specific dictionary of dictionary into pandas dataframe - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have dictionary as shown below

d1:

```
{'teachers': 49, 
      'students': 289,  
      'R': 3.7, 
      'holidays': 165, 
      'Em': {'from': '2020-02-29T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-03-20T20:00:00.000Z', 
                  'F': 3, 'C': 2},
      'OS':18 
      'sC': {'from': '2020-03-31T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-05-29T20:00:00.000Z', 
                  'F': 25, 'C': 31}}
```

I would like to convert above dictionary as a dataframe as shown below in pandas.

```
teachers  students R   holidays  Em_from     Em_to       Exam_F  Exam_C  OS  sC_from         sC_to     sC_F   sC_C
49        289      3.7 165       2020-02-29  2020-03-20  3       2       18  2020-03-31  2020-05-29    25     31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize):

```
d = {'teachers': 49,
      'students': 289,
      'R': 3.7,
      'holidays': 165,
      'Em': {'from': '2020-02-29T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-03-20T20:00:00.000Z',
                  'F': 3, 'C': 2},
      'OS':18,
      'sC': {'from': '2020-03-31T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-05-29T20:00:00.000Z',
                  'F': 25, 'C': 31}}


print(pd.json_normalize(d, sep='_'))
```

Prints:

```
   teachers  students    R  ...                     sC_to  sC_F sC_C
0        49       289  3.7  ...  2020-05-29T20:00:00.000Z    25   31

[1 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: Added similar question, pls look into this, if you have some time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364989/convert-a-dictionary-of-dictionary-into-a-row-wise-dataframe-in-pandas