# Convert a dictionary of dictionary into a row wise dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have dictionary as shown below

d1:

```
{'teachers': 49, 
      'students': 289,  
      'R': 3.7, 
      'holidays': 165, 
      'E': {'from': '2020-02-29T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-03-20T20:00:00.000Z', 
                  'F': 3, 'C': 2},
      'OS':18 
      'sC': {'from': '2020-03-31T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-05-29T20:00:00.000Z', 
                  'F': 25, 'C': 31}}
```

I would like to convert above dictionary as a dataframe as shown below in pandas.

```
Params     Value
teachers   49
students   289
R          3.7
holidays   165
E_from     2020-02-29
E_to       2020-03-20
E_F        3
E_C        2
OS         18
sC_from    2020-03-31
sC_to      2020-05-29
sC_F       25
sC_C       31
```

The df should have two columns with heading 'params' and 'value'

Comment: `pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, sep='_').loc[0]
`, and the question is almost the same , I will close it by the same question asked before ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json_normalize` and then tranpose the dataframe:

```
d = {'teachers': 49,
      'students': 289,
      'R': 3.7,
      'holidays': 165,
      'Em': {'from': '2020-02-29T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-03-20T20:00:00.000Z',
                  'F': 3, 'C': 2},
      'OS':18,
      'sC': {'from': '2020-03-31T20:00:00.000Z', 'to': '2020-05-29T20:00:00.000Z',
                  'F': 25, 'C': 31}}


df=pd.json_normalize(d, sep='_').T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Params',0:'Value'})
```

Output:

```
df
Params                       Value
teachers                        49
students                       289
R                              3.7
holidays                       165
OS                              18
Em_from   2020-02-29T20:00:00.000Z
Em_to     2020-03-20T20:00:00.000Z
Em_F                             3
Em_C                             2
sC_from   2020-03-31T20:00:00.000Z
sC_to     2020-05-29T20:00:00.000Z
sC_F                            25
sC_C                            31
```

Comment: edited the question, pls modify your answer

Comment: ready, edited! @Danish

Comment: @Danish - You're welcome! Happy coding!